# Check if object fits into browser cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, jstorage

I have a single page application, which loads a `JSON` data file from a server and displays it on the client. The data file only changes once per day, so after fetching it, I want to keep it cached on the client. So far, I have been using `jStorage` and am happy with the overall result. One thing is problematic though: according to the [jStorage Browser support page](http://www.jstorage.info/), the cache size varies from browser to browser.

So my question: can I somehow find out if `jStorage` will be able to store all my data? The `jStorage` website itself does not give any clues to that.

Alternatively, since I'm only storing one big object, I could use a plug-in like [sizeOf](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/finding-the-memory-usage-of-objects/) to check the object size before saving it, but I don't know if that is a reliable approach.

Comment: how big is your data regularly?

Comment: Currently it's ~ 4mb, so close to the limit of some browsers. It can be 6-7mb in a few month and I don't want to go hunting for non-findable entries just because `jStorage` cuts the data off when it cannot hold it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `jStorage` implements, you say 5mb so I guess it's using `localstorage`. Have you tried `indexedDB` which is browser native and theoretically limit to your hard drive capacity.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API